# Nginx server connect to Java Spring with SSL

Tags: java, spring, ssl, nginx, https

I have 2 Docker containers, one with nginx using SSL(443) and one with Java/spring api which also needs to be exposed on HTTPS(8443).

The java certificate I converted from the front end certificate and I created a .p12 certificate, used like this:

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
        key-store: certificate.p12
        key-store-password: 123456
        key-store-type: PKCS12
```

This is the nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass https://app.site.com:8443;
        }

        location /signin {
            proxy_pass https://app.site.com:8443;
        }

        location /social/signup {
            proxy_pass https://app.site.com:8443;
        }

        server_name app.competithor.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
      }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/app.site.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/app.site.com.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass https://app.site.com:8443;
            proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
            proxy_ssl_name $host;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;

            proxy_set_header  Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        }

        location /signin {
            proxy_pass https://app.site.com:8443;
            proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
            proxy_ssl_name $host;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;

            proxy_set_header  Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        }

        location /social/signup {
            proxy_pass https://app.site.com:8443;
           proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
           proxy_ssl_name $host;
           proxy_ssl_server_name on;

           proxy_set_header  Host              $host;
           proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        }
    }
}
```

I always have this error:
[error] 6#6: *4 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure) while SSL handshaking to upstream

I've tried many settings in nginx and java config, but the same error. Do anybody knows how can this handshake/connection work?

UPDATE: The java app is Maven, should I configure the keystore in the mvnw file?

UPDATE2:
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 returns:
CONNECTED(00000003)

### 140514309248664:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:

### no peer certificate available

### No client certificate CA names sent

### SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes

New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1549049020
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Comment: Did you add SSL keystores to java application ? . share those config

Comment: What do you mean to add SSL keystores, where do I have to add them? Isn't the certificate.p12 the keystore? Or this should be added on the Docker server somewhere?

Comment: share the java keystore configurations to find out whats happening, did you specify that keystore type as (.p12). Did you ensure that java application served over https?

Comment: The .p12 certificate is in the same folder with the java app.
The java configuration is also in my post:
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
        key-store: certificate.p12
        key-store-password: 123456
        key-store-type: PKCS12
I have docker run: docker run -d -it -p 8443:8443 <container>

Comment: Should the certificate.p12 file be in the same folder as the application.yml ?

Comment: Add in trust stores as well. Share the Java container logs too

Comment: I've managed to install the certificate in keystore, but I still have the same error on the frontend container. The java container shows no error.

Comment: Share your project in GitHub, will take a look

Comment: What does 'openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443' return?

Comment: The java project is here:https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3d4a044c0e14b3a4d8c8ed061ab290ff20190201192149/0cd139367e3c6ba088ecb5837eaa809420190201192149/100938

Comment: @Barath did you have time to take a look on the code? You have any feedback? Thanks.